# How to do multiple split values from a list of string to an object, blows if there is no string to split

Tags: c#, string, linq, list, split

howto do multiple split values from a list of string to an object, Blows if there is no string to split

I want to split this

```
List<string> CrossReference = new List<string>
    {
         "task #1443; task #1447; task #1444; task #973; rel #33; sprint #815",
         ""
    };
```

First by

> ;

then by

> #

I have this class

```
public class CrossReference
{
    public long Aid { get; set; }
    public string TaskType { get; set; }
}
```

and I have this test

```
[TestMethod]
public void splitTest()
{
    List<string> CrossReference = new List<string>
    {
         "task #1443; task #1447; task #1444; task #973; rel #33; sprint #815",
         ""
    };

    foreach (var str in CrossReference)
    {
        var str1 = str.Trim().Split(';')
                    .Select(x => new CrossReference
                    {
                        TaskType = (string)x.Split(new char[] { '#' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0],
                        Aid = Convert.ToInt64(x.Split(new char[] { '#' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1]),
                    }).ToList();
    }
}
```

The value of str1 in the first run is ok, but in the second run blows up because I don´t have anything to split.

How can I prevent the case that there is no string to split.

Thanks in advance

Jolynice

Comment: check your string contains both before you start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check str is empty or have just white spaces

```
 if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str))
```

Comment: Hello Tugberk, I appreciate your solution also but I will use Levent solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
you can skip empty rows..

 var str1 = str.Trim().Split(';')
                .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x) && x.Split(new char[] { '#' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Any())
                .Select(x => new CrossReference
                {
                    TaskType = (string)x.Split(new char[] { '#' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0],
                    Aid = Convert.ToInt64(x.Split(new char[] { '#' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1]),
                }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks Levent , Is working fine. thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I'll just point out that you can use 2 combined `Linq`functions for that :

```
CrossReference
    .SelectMany(str => 
        str.Split(new char[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            .Select(kv => { 
                string[] pair = kv.Trim().Split(new char[] { '#' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                return new CrossReference { TaskType = pair[0].Trim(), Aid = long.Parse(pair[1].Trim()); 
            }
        )
    );
```

*( Explanation )*

`SelectMany` - Will combine all of the splitted string into one `IEnumerable<string>` where each of `string`s will look like `"<name> #<long_value>"`

`Select` - will then return object that you process inside of the expression which in my example is basically trimming all white spaces on the both ends of the string then it splits it up by `#` character and then pack it into the `CrossReference` object.

`Select` operation is called inside of the `SelectMany` just to process results in one run and not run it double time ( to split and then process ).

There's no need for trim at the beginnign and theres no need to check if the string is empty or not because of `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` parameter passed into the `Split` method.